# Can I jump to a specific div ID based on the results of a specific variable passed from another page?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, javascript, anchor-tags

I am trying to jump to a specific section on my page, but I need to do it after the `document.ready` has completed. When I click from page 1, information is added to the end of the URL depending on which button is pushed. When I arrive at page 2, the URL ends in something like this `.aspx?Org=Exec`.

I have a variable on page 2 that pulls that `Exec` out and now I want to run an if statement that says `If the variable == Exec` then jump to the div with the id of `exec` on this page

I have no idea where to even start with this to get it to work, so I don't have much sample code to provide. I must stress that I need this to occur after the page has finished loading. Normal HTML anchors wouldn't work for this situation.

So, this is what will be clicked from page 1:

```
 <div onclick="location.href='https://websitename/SitePages/ContactUs.aspx?Org=Exec'">Executive Administration</div>
```

Then when we arrive on page 2, we have this inside document ready:

```
    var anchor = window.location.href.split('?Org=')[1];

    if(anchor == 'Exec'){
       insert some way to jump to div id="exec" 
    }
```

so what do I put in the if statement to make it move straight to the anchor?

Please let me know if I need to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery. Use following

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var divId = getQueryString("Org");

    if(divId != null && divId == 'Exec') {
        jQuery("body").animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#exec").offset().top});
    }
});

function getQueryString(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Another approach is by modifying the URL and appending the target page div id as part of it. So something like

```
https://websitename/SitePages/ContactUs.aspx#exec
```

So the above URL will take the user directly to the div having id = `exec`

Comment: I get an error: Unable to get value of the property 'top': object is null or undefined.

Do I need to have a jQuery(document).ready? I use $(document).ready now because it contains SPServices as well.

Comment: Is your div id (exec) correct?

Comment: Fixed the div id (oops) and now I don't get the error, but it does not jump to that div properly. The page loads a ton of appended information from SPServices to multiple divs, so I need the anchor to engage after SPServices is finished appending the information.

Comment: @Caola Ok in that case you need to call this after your `SPServices` code. Also take a note at my updated answer.

Comment: I tried the url with the #exec but it doesn't work properly because all of the divs are squished at the top of the page until the SPServices information loads. Once that loads, the page spreads out considerably. So yes, it is anchoring at the div, but after the document loads, that div is now much further down the page.

I put the if statement after the SPServices code already.

Sorry, I am still learning all of this!

Comment: Ok. In that case you should put the code after the code which populate the div.

Comment: Unfortunately, all of the divs are populated with things from SPServices. This is why I am so stuck on the issue. I was hoping there was some way to do it after the page loads.

Comment: Replace the jQuery(document).ready(function() to function goThere() and call this function inside the SPServises.